# Nodejs installing wrong version when trying to install nodejs 10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

So i am trying to install Nodejs v10 and npm but when i run the command

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
```

and

```
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

It would install Nodejs v4.2.6 and i don't understand why and it dosent even install npm with it i need to install it separately
maybe you guys can help me

Comment: You can install nodejs via `nvm`. There you can selece which version of node js you want to choose from all node js version. You can learn how to install nvm in this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04#how-to-install-using-nvm

Comment: another way to install nodejs is first you have to run `sudo apt update`. then `sudo apt install nodejs` then `sudo apt install npm` to completely install nodejs completely

Comment: the nvm didnt work and i tried to use sudp aot install npm and nodejs but it would install the v4 too and i need v10

Comment: before running `sudo apt install` you need to run `sudo apt update` 1st. Have you tried that??

Comment: Why `nvm` didn't working???

Comment: yes i did try that

Comment: it would just show a lot of things for like 15 m and nothing happened

Comment: what os and version is your pc running??

Comment: the server im running for this is vmware ubuntu server 16.04.6

Comment: *update* i tried nvm again and waited 30 mins and it worked thank you

Answer (score -3):

you need install node with nvm (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) follow this intruttions for install the version of you want